# iphone/ipad how to handle lots of input fields?

Tags: ios

I'm writing a app that contains quite a bit of input fields for collecting data.
and im wondering what are some good methods to display these kind of input fields, if there are too many to fit on a screen? so something like the add contact screen... where u can scroll down and there are fields there

my initial idea is to put them in a scroll view and then i can scroll through them, is there a tutorial to do this? it seems like the scroll view is more for dynamically displaying data like a text view, and not for static forms like i was describing.

if anyone has any different methods for doing this please post.

Comment: Why not just an `UITableView`?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason table view just didnt come to me, ill try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableview will match perfectly for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My friend wrote this which is a container view that automatically helps with moving fields out of the way of the keyboard - It will certainly save you some time if you don't want to use a UITableView:

https://github.com/mackross/GTKeyboardHelper

The other way as H2CO3 suggested is to use a UITableView. If it is a UITableViewController, then you get the moving out of the keyboards way automatically. You could build custom table view cells that are styled to have a prompt and a UITextField for input. You can also set the selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to prevent these cells from highlighting when selected.

I think the third way is to do this with a UINavigationController (or a UIPageControl) and build a kind of wizard, where you go through various pages of related data. This might be the neatest way depending on how many fields you have and if you can group data into common sets (e.g. personal information, work information etc)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found GTKeyboardHelper to be an easy way out.

After drag and drop the framework in your project, include the header file.
Download and open the example project, then drag the "Keyboard Helper" object from the objects section in the xib to the objects section in your project's interface builder.

Drag and drop all your views to be children of the "Keyboard Helper".